# GitLab is unreachable in my browser after installation

Tags: gitlab

I have installed GitLab following the instructions [here](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) on the gitlab website for centos. I have ruby version 2.1.2 installed and mysql. And a bunch of other programs. I set the external url to git.mywebsite.com, but when i go to the url nothing is there. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstall it many time. Am I missing a key piece to make this work? How can I get gitlab working?

Comment: Are you updating production in config/gitlab.yml?

Comment: I have not done that, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update config/gitlab.yml production configuration:

```
production: &base
  #
  # 1. GitLab app settings
  # ==========================

  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: domain.tld
    port: 8888
    https: false
```

Then restart gitlab.

As I am running other web services, I am using Nginx to proxy my GitLab instance.  My installation followed the [Ubuntu manual install instructions available from GitHub](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md).

Your install may feature a Ruby configuration at: `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

After editing your gitlab.rb configuration, execute the following to reconfigure:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Then restart GitLab:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
sudo gitlab-ctl start
```

Comment: were do I find the config/gitlab.yml file?

Comment: /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml - depending on your OS.

Comment: After I add the above code then reconfigure gitlab I get an error saying it wasn't expecting '&base'

Comment: sudo gitlab-ctl status:
run: nginx: (pid 1252) 1s; run: log: (pid 32043) 122s
run: postgresql: (pid 1251) 1s; down: log: 1s, normally up, want up
run: redis: (pid 1250) 1s; down: log: 1s, normally up, want up
run: sidekiq: (pid 32019) 124s; down: log: 1s, normally up, want up
run: unicorn: (pid 32018) 124s; down: log: 1s, normally up, want up

Comment: If you're editing the gitlab.rb, don't copy the gitlab.yml configuration - just add the host and port to gitlab.rb.  There are numerous factors in play from installation method, dependent services, and routing to your subdomain.  We can chat; or, maybe you should choose an easier installation method like Chef Solo.

Comment: so what worked is I added external_url "http://gitlab.example.com:8888" adding the port did the job